# What are some good methods of implementing RTS-style Box selection?

Tags: camera, rts, selection

I'm scouting around for different methods of implementing a typical RTS box selection. This is for 3D game - so I'm looking for methods for finding units within selection box in 3D world. Here is a quick screenshot of what a box selection looks like in 2D Starcraft:

[image: Starcraft Screenshot]

Comment: do you need help drawing the box or do you need help deciding which units go in the box?

Comment: "because I find visual stimulus quite helpful" And yet, you failed to explain exactly what you were looking for. We all know what box selection is, but which part: the box drawing or the selecting? Is this a 3D game where one might have perspective issues, or is it a 2D game? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry about being unclear, I am asking about the actual selection of units

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question was vague, but the answer to both interpretations could be simple.

Heres some pseudo code:

```
vec2 original_xy = get_mouse_position();
vec2 new_xy;

while (get_mouse_click_state() == MOUSE_DOWN) {
        new_xy = get_mouse_position();
        render_box(original_xy, new_xy);
        ...
        context_swap_buffers();
}

vec2 a = mouse_to_world(original_xy);
vec2 b = mouse_to_world(new_xy),

const float max_height = 100.f; // maximum search height
BoundingBox aabb(vec3(min(a.x, b.x), min(a.y, b.y), 0), vec3(max(a.x, b.x), max(a.y, b.y), max_height));
List<Object> objects_in_box;

for Object x in all_objects do {
    if (x.collides(aabb)) {
        list.add(x);
    }    
}
```

Comment: render_window_box() must render properly using the window coordinates, probably use an orthographic projection matrix instead of whatever you use for the rest of your rendering. See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/obtaining-a-world-point-from-a-screen-point-with-an-orthographic-projection.

Comment: mouse_to_world() must convert the 2D coordinates of the mouse to 2D/3D coordinates relative to your world. This can be done in a few ways, here is a GD:SE topic on the matter for OpenGL: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8974/converting-a-mouse-click-to-a-ray.

Comment: Why use a bounding box,
you could simply translate top left and bottom right point from 2d screen coords to 3d world coords,
next iterate trough all units and see if x and y coords are in the rectangle definde by those 3d coords.

Comment: This seems to be the most popular (maybe only?) solution from what ive read - I reckon I will use this in conjunction with my existing cell partitioning system, to get an O(constant) time search rather than an O(n) time with the for loop

Comment: @Thomas you do realise that is exactly what the bounding box above does? Albeit with a 3rd dimension attached. If you have a 2D bounding box implementation, it would be the same approach; just without the Z component.

Comment: I know this works the same, might be faster though since you don't need to create a boundingbox object every time. I don't know how the .collides method performs, but a simple integer < and > check seems faster to me.

Comment: @Thomas if your compiler is in any way modern, and you use optimization flags; I'm guessing there should be no added cost for the AABB creation; and the collision method should be equally fast; doing only what is required. Chances are the whole thing will be inlined to just a few operations. If you experience performance problems, perhaps rather than test against `all_objects`, only test against objects that are being rendered (ie, on screen).